# What is difference between size_hint_max, size_hint_min and size_hint in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am not getting what is difference between `size_hint_max`, `size_hint_min`, `size_hint` in kivy.

I know that `size_hint_max` will use `size_hint_max_x` and `size_hint_max_y` for its `ReferenceList` property, but when does this thing will make difference??

Can someone explian me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. The `size_hint` is used to calculate the size of the `Widget`. If the calculated size is greater than the `size_hint_max`, then it is set to the  `size_hint_max` (similar for `size_hint_min`). Note that `size_hint_max` and `size_hint_min` are in pixels and are only valid for containers that honor them (like `FloatLayout`).

See [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=size_hint_max#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_max_x)

Comment: oh! I just didn't read that property in documentation. Thank you!